# subprocess.run not throwing errors on stderr when using msvc compiler cl.exe as command

Tags: python, subprocess

Python 3.12.0, Windows 10, MSVC 14.3

```py
from subprocess import run
command = ['cl', ...]
proc = run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, text=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output = proc.stdout.splitlines()
errors = proc.stderr.splitlines()
```

When compiler is not producing any errors then list **errors** is empty but when compiler is throwing errors, it goes to list **output** instead of list **errors**. This is not the case when using mingw32 tool chain on windows. The error messages goes into list **errors** in case of any errors produced while compilation. It seems msvc compiler cl.exe is throwing error messages to stdout instead of stderr.

How do you correctly pass errors to **errors** list?

One option I can think of is is to pass errors to stdout and check the return code. If it's not 0 then I believe the process has thrown some errors and you can parse the output list for further investigation. Am I right here?

Comment: If the command is writing errors to the standard output stream (rather than the standard error stream) then that's not really a Python issue

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's idea, what goes to stdout and stderr are a bit different from what you would expect. With cl, the header/copyright information goes to stderr, everything else to stdout.

```
# Full output
$ cl /c hello.c
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.38.33135 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

hello.c
hello.c(3): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '}'

# stderr only
$ cl /c hello.c >/dev/null
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.38.33135 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


# stdout only
$ cl /c hello.c 2>/dev/null
hello.c
hello.c(3): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '}'
```